# How to specify "Date with timestamp" format in Text File Input step of Pentaho?

Tags: format, timestamp, pentaho, kettle

I have timestamp like **`2016-04-04T01:00:11Z`**

Could someone please tell me how to specify the format for this timestamp in `Text File Input` step of Pentaho?

I tried with `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ` and `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ` but either doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

We can use this format String: ***yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'***

Answer (score 0):

This way: **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX**